# How to extract the first three digits after the decimal point in any calculation in Perl?

Tags: perl, integer-division

For a simple division like 1/3, if I want to extract only the first three digits after the decimal point from the result of division, then how can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with **spritnf**:

```
my $rounded = sprintf("%.3f", 1/3);
```

This isn't this `sprintf`'s purpose, but it does the job.

If you want just three digits after the dot, you can do it with math computations:

```
my $num = 1/3;
my $part;
$part = $1 if $num=~/^\d+\.(\d{3})/;
print "3 digits after dot: $part\n" if defined $part;
```

Comment: @ikegami Yes sprintf is formatting function its not very graceful to use like this IMO

Comment: Note that the `sprintf` solution rounds, but the second one doesn't. One of them is bound to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Using sprintf and some pattern matching. Verbose.

```
my $str;
my $num = 1/3;
my $res = sprintf("%.3f\n",$num);
($str = $res) =~ s/^0\.//;
print "$str\n";
```

Comment: Note `s/^0\.//` regex can fail when you have **setlocale** to some locales, such as Russian.

Comment: @PSIAlt, I thought locales only mattered under `use locale;`. Are you sure?

Comment: @ikegami yes `perl -MPOSIX -e 'setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF8");printf "%.3f", 1/3;'` prints `0,333` for me.

Comment: @PSIAlt, Since a single period matches a single character. Does that not get rid of the locale issue? Is there another reason to avoid using a single period in the regex? By single period, I mean not escaping the period.

Comment: @fbynite oh, i got the idea. I think its "too-unstrict", but should work too